# Error in ITSA modelling in R using ITS.analysis: `contrasts<-`

Tags: r, time-series

I'm carrying out itsa using library(its.analysis) and I have one data frame that works, however my new data set produces the following error:
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I can't spot the difference between the working and non-working datasets:
Both datasets (via class) are data.frame.
Both datasets (via glimpse) are:

```
$ Date        <date> 2012-10-17, …
$ Time        <chr> "Before", …
$ dep_var     <dbl> 97, …
$ interuption <dbl> 0, …
```

Could it be that there are not enough observations of my 'after' condition?
If I add on three made up dates/values, then the itsa anlaysis works, indeed even a single extra date works.

I.e. my original data set, that works, has 24 'before' values and nine 'after' values.
My new data set that causes the error has 18 'before' values and six 'after' values
And the edited data set that also works has 18 before values and nine after values, and it also works with only seven after values (the six real ones and one made up set).

Is seven 'after' values the minimum cut off or can I get the analysis to run with 6 values if I rejig any other parameters?

The odd thing is that in the example data provided by the package, (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/its.analysis/versions/1.6.0/topics/itsa.model) there are three time periods with six, nine and four observations each, so it's not obvious why two time periods with 18 and 6 observations wouldn't work.

The data is:

```
time <- as.Date(c("2014-01-15", "2015-04-13", "2015-04-29", "2015-09-25",
          "2015-12-06", "2016-02-02", "2016-04-13",
          "2016-08-13", "2017-02-01", "2017-09-13", "2017-09-25",
          "2019-01-29", "2019-04-01", "2019-07-23",
          "2020-01-04", "2020-07-15", "2020-12-13", "2020-12-15",
          "2021-03-19", "2021-04-18", "2022-01-23",
          "2022-08-19", "2023-02-13", "2024-02-23"))
interruption <- c(rep(0, 18), rep(1, 6))
depvar <- as.numeric(c(65, 64, 63, 81, 70, 70, 72, 68, 74, 75, 
74, 63, 63, 64, 65, 61, 64, 64, 53, 54, 57, 54, 54, 54))

time2 <- c(time, as.Date(c("2024-04-01", "2024-05-01", "2024-06-01")))
interruption2 <- c(interruption, c(1,1,1))
depvar2 <- c(depvar, as.numeric(c(55, 53, 55)))

time4 <- c(time, as.Date(c("2024-04-01")))
interruption4 <- c(interruption, c(1))
depvar4 <- c(depvar, as.numeric(c(45)))

Join5 <- data.frame(time = time, 
                    depvar= depvar, 
                    interruption = interruption)
Join7 <- data.frame(time = time4, 
                    depvar= depvar4, 
                    interruption = interruption4)

Model <- itsa.model(data= Join5,
                    time="time",
                    depvar="depvar",
                    interrupt_var = "interruption",
                    alpha=0.005,
                    bootstrap=TRUE, Reps = 1000)
```